# Running ruby in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, ruby-lsp

I've installed ruby lsp and code runner extensions in VScode.

I'm running the following code in VScode

```rb
puts ("enter a number")
x = gets.to_i
puts ("enter a second number")
y = gets.to_i
result = x + y
puts result
```

IN terminal panel it says

> "running C:\Users\Asus\ruby\helloworld.rb"
> The program is not running